# JQuery Slide in multiple divs sequentially

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, slidetoggle

I have some jquery code like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //alert('jquery');
  $(".ldiv").hide();
  $(".ldiv").each(function(index, elem) {
    elem.id = "ldiv" + elem;
  });
  $(".ldiv").click(function () {
    //alert(this.innerHTML); //works
  });
  $(".ldiv").slideToggle();

});
```

This works: All divs slide in. But what I'd like to do is to have each one slide in separately, with the next one starting after the previous one has finished.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `complete` callback mentioned in [**slideToggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

```
var index = 0;
$(".ldiv:eq(0)").slideToggle(callback);

function callback() {
    if (index < $(".ldiv").length) {
        index++;
        $(".ldiv:eq(" + index + ")").slideToggle(callback);
    }
}
```